# On the right half-plane, what is an upper bound for $\frac{1}{\log(z+2)}$?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, contour-integration, residue-calculus

I am trying to estimate some factors in my integrand in complex integration, and I think the upper bound for $\frac {1}{log(z+2)}$ on the semicircle in the *right* half plane is just $\frac {1}{log(2)}$.  Anything wrong with this upper bound?  I'm probably just overthinking this one, but wanted to make sure.

My parameterization is:

z= iy, $-R \le y \le R$ on the imaginary axis

z= $Re^{i\theta}$ on the semi-circle in the RHP,

and I let R grow to infinity.

Thanks,

Comment: Yes: $\log(z+2) = \log|z+2| + i \arg(z+2)$, so $|\log(z+2)| \ge \log|z+2| \ge 2$.

Comment: ...did you mean log(2) for the last term on the R.H.S. of your last inequality @GregMartin?  Thanks,